# Unclear MotionLayout parameters

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

Could anyone please explain what MotionLayout's onSwipe parameters *touchAnchorId* and *touchAnchorSide* do? This is what documentation says about touchAnchorId

> View that is being moved by the swipe.

That doesn't make sense to me as swiping on MotionLayout doesn't move a single view. Swiping progresses transition between starting constraintSet and ending constraintSet. I thought initially that *touchAnchorId* would specify a view that user will have to drag to progress animation but this isn't a case and MotionLayout developer team introduced *touchRegionId* parameter for that. It's also unclear to me what *touchAnchorSide* is supposed to do as I don't see any difference when changing its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onSwipe Move progress from 0 to 1 along a
direction(dragDirection=) horizontal (dragRight/Left/StartEnd) or vertical (dragUp/Down)

If I drag my finger a 100 pixels along the screen how much does it move from 0 to 1?
That is the main question most of the other argument answer.
with out an anchor it uses the full length of the layout.

But if you are making a pull out draw that is excessive.
You could adjust it with dragScale. But how much? The pull may vary based on constraints fonts many things.

Many times you want it to act as if you are pulling a view or a side of a view. In which case you ned to the View (touchAnchorId) and the side of the view (touchAnchorSide)

Sometimes you want to limit the region in which the swipe will work
In which case you can use limitBoundsTo.

Much of the rest of the flags are bout what to do when you lift your finger.
There is much more subtly in all the use-cases it is designed to support.

Comment: I understand now concept behind touchAnchorId. Thank you. I still don't know what's the point of touchAnchorSide. What does it mean to act as if I'm pulling side of a view? I don't see any difference when adjusting this parameter.

Comment: If the view does not change size it does not matter.  If the view is changing size it makes all the difference. You may have the left side stay fixed and right side expand. 

Here I am explaining it:
https://youtu.be/8McWIOhh7aA?t=1138

Comment: @hoford Great video!!! I struggled with the understanding of those two attributes for quite some time. Great visual explanation.

Comment: ok, what should i do for speed up to finger reaction by Carousel in constraintLayout.helper? dragScale is not working